# FunctionInterpolation on a 2D function does not match original function when plotted together

Tags: interpolation

I met with a problem when trying to find the interpolation function of a 2 variable function. The function is like below (already simplified for brevity):

```
testfun = x/(1 + y^2);
```

Then, use `FunctionInterpolation` to find the interpolation function:

```
intfun = FunctionInterpolation[ testfun, {y, -20, 20}, {x, 0, 2}];
```

If I plot the original function and the interpolation function together, the plot looks like this:

```
p1 = Plot[testfun /. x -> 1, {y, -20, 20}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red];
p2 = Plot[intfun[x, 1], {x, -20, 20}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Blue];
Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

The `FunctionInterpolation` normally works well with simple functions (like `fun = x^2+a`), but I don't know what lead to the result like this. Anyone have an idea? Thanks!

And the 3D-plot for 2 variables is shown as below:

```
Plot3D[{testfun, intfun[y, x]}, {y, -20, 20}, {x, 0, 2}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

[image]

Comment: "Two variable interpolation function" means that the function to be interpolated is of two variables, generally $x$ and $y$.  You have a *one*-dimensional function.

Comment: David, thanks for your reply! I do have $x$ and $y$ in the function.

Comment: Plot the *two*-dimensional function, not a *one*-dimensional slice of it.

Comment: Please see above.

Answer (score 4):

### Short Answer

You need to set the [`InterpolationPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolationPoints.html) to a higher value than the default in order to get a decent result out of [`FunctionInterpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionInterpolation.html).  For this example, 125 is the lowest I found that gives a good plot,

```
testfun[y_, x_] := x/(1 + y^2);
intfun = FunctionInterpolation[testfun[y, x], {y, -20, 20}, {x, 0, 2},
    InterpolationPoints -> 125];
Plot[{testfun[y, 1], intfun[y, 1]}, {y, -20, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Long Answer

Let's look at the default options for `FunctionInterpolation`,

```
Options[FunctionInterpolation]
(* {InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
 InterpolationPrecision -> Automatic, AccuracyGoal -> Automatic, 
 PrecisionGoal -> Automatic, InterpolationPoints -> 11, 
 MaxRecursion -> 6} *)
```

What `InterpolationPoints` means is that for every variable, the input range is subdivided into 11 points.  Let's take the default result from `FunctionInterpolation` and see if we can recreate it using `Interpolation`.

```
intfun1 = FunctionInterpolation[testfun[y, x], {y, -20, 20}, {x, 0, 2}]
interpolatingdata = 
  Table[{{y, x}, testfun[y, x]}, {y, Subdivide[-20, 20, 10]}, {x, 
     Subdivide[0, 2, 10]}]~Flatten~1;
intfun2 = Interpolation[interpolatingdata]
intfun1 == intfun2
```

[image]

You can see from the last line that the results are identical.  By plotting the actual input points alongside the plot, you can see that the resulting interpolating function **does** go through the points, it just doesn't correctly reproduce the regions in between:

```
Plot[{testfun[y, 1], intfun1[y, 1], intfun2[y, 1]}, {y, -20, 20}, 
  PlotRange -> All]~Show~
 Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], 
   Point@Cases[interpolatingdata, {{a_, 1}, b_} :> {a, b}, Infinity]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Why do you need to use so many points?  I'm no expert, but I would say it is because your function is not a polynomial, and the documentation says

> `Interpolation` works by fitting polynomial curves between successive data points

Interestingly, if you had tried this as a one-dimensional function from the start, `FunctionInterpolation` would automatically increase the number of `InterpolationPoints`:

```
testfun[y_, x_] := x/(1 + y^2);
intfun = FunctionInterpolation[testfun[y, 1], {y, -20, 20}];
Plot[{testfun[y, 1], intfun[y]}, {y, -20, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

You can see the number of points that were finally used with

```
Length[intfun[[3, 1]]]
(* 133 *)
```

Why it doesn't recursively increase the number of points for a 2D function is not clear - the documentation for `FunctionInterpolation` is sparse.  Could be a bug, or expected behavior.